# Nuget VS Web Deploy

Tags: nuget, webdeploy

We are currently using web deploy for creating packages for our .net web applications. It got some pros and cons. Now we are going to use nuget for dependency management but given the ease of packaging in nuget .. i am debating on should i still use web deploy + remote service or try to use nuget to bundle my web application and use powershell or something like octupus to deploy ??

For my web deploy becomes little complex when even try to do simple things like include , exlcude , gac or registry or iis config ( which again not very flexible ).

But on the other hand it comes with remote service and all i need to do is through the package to the service and i am done..

Please give your inputs on this comparison.

-raj

Answer (score 1):

NuGet is a dependency manager, and as such is appropriate for use at development/build, not deployment time. From a deployment perspective, it doesn't offer you any more than what a zip file does... except all the overhead of trying to fit NuGet in the process.

Take a look at Inedo's [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster). It can take care of the process from source control through production deployment. There's also a free version that will most certainly handle your requirements, and it also has a module to manage your configuration files so you don't need to worry about doing transforms.

(disclaimer: I work for Inedo)

Comment: NuGet works great for deployment. I've used to to keep client apps and web apps up to date, without having to do much fiddling around.

Answer (score 1):

I am setting up a system that uses NuGet and Webdeploy.

NuGet is used as the repository format, so the build system publishes NuGet packaged artifacts.

The Deployment systemn uses NuGet to get the RIGHT packaged artifact from the NuGet repository.

The build artififact happens to be WebDeploy for easy installation.

I am still working out if I am going to use puppet, chef or octupus to orchastrate the deployment.

Comment: Hey, can u give me the script for web deploy with Nuget?

Comment: As i've changed employers (and continents) I don't have access to it anymore. It was trivially simple.  Use nuget to extract the latest version, then run a command to install the WebDeploy package.